# Why do I get a memory error?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
i=int(input("enter your number"))
j=int(input("enter your number"))
if i>j: #making x always greater than y
    x=i
    y=j
elif i<j:
    x=j
    y=i
else:
    print("invalid")
k=y
cyclelength=[]
while k<=x:
    list=[k]
    while k!=1:
        if(k%2==0):
            k=i//2
        else:
            k=3*k+1
        list.append(k)
    cyclelength.append(len(list))
    k+=1
print(y," ",x," ",max(cyclelength))
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/uva100.py", line 21, in <module>
    list.append(k)
MemoryError
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: `k` is never going to be `1` you run out of space in memory from all the appends.

Comment: As a general comment for readability, you should use more meaningful variable names than simple letters (unless dealing with VERY simple and short algorithms, or some conventions like using 'i' as the loop-variable in a for-loop). It'll make maintaining your code much easier in the future.

Comment: To make debugging easier, add 
import sys;print k;sys.stdout.flush()
inside of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another problem in this block:

```
while k!=1:
    if(k%2==0):
        k //= 2
    else:
        k=3*k+1
```

k has the value 1 when you exit.

So you increment k to 2, reenter the while because k < x and reset k to 1

--> infinite loop

you have to define a new variable in you inner while or extract this block in another function

Answer (score 5):

You might mean `k //= 2` instead of `k=i//2`

```py
def cyclelength(k):
    assert k > 0
    count = 1
    while k != 1:
       k = k // 2 if k % 2 == 0 else 3 * k + 1
       count += 1
    return count

k_with_max_cyclelength = max(range(y, x+1), key=cyclelength)
```

Or to get both:

```py
k, max_cyclelength = max(((k, cyclelength(k)) for k in range(y, x+1)),
                         key=lambda pair: pair[1])
```

Comment: +1 because that seems to implement the algorithm the OP intended, and very readably, too. The algorithm doesn't actually work (for example, if you give it 0, or a negative number, for the lower value, and obviously it can never become positive…), but that's not your fault.

Comment: @abarnert: I've added the assertion but invalid `y` should be discarded earlier.

Comment: The point is that it's only an unproven conjecture that the 3x+1 iteration converges for all positive x, so, unless you can prove the conjecture (or solve the halting problem, which of course you can't), there's no way to provide a successful implementation for the OP's algorithm. I just brought up negative numbers because those quite obviously diverge, and therefore highlight the problem. Again, your implementation is what the OP intended, and it's not your fault that it doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going for

```
n=y
cyclelength=[]
while n<=x:
    k=n
    list=[k]
    while k!=1:
        if(k%2==0):
            k//=2
        else:
            k=3*k+1
        list.append(k)
    cyclelength.append(len(list))
    n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're playing with the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). Try

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def sequence_length(k):
    length = 0
    while k > 1:
        k = 3*k+1 if k&1 else k//2
        length += 1
    return length

def max_sequence_length(lo, hi):
    best_k, best_length = None, 0
    for k in xrange(lo, hi+1):
        length = sequence_length(k)
        if length > best_length:
            best_k, best_length = k, length
    return best_k, best_length

def main():
    lo = get_int("Enter the start number: ")
    hi = get_int("Enter the finish number: ")
    lo, hi = min(lo, hi), max(lo, hi)
    best_k, best_length = max_sequence_length(lo, hi)
    print("In {}..{}, max cycle length is {} at k = {}".format(lo, hi, best_length, best_k))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```